# Why don't cars use Sequential gearboxes?

Tags: transmission, sequential-transmission

I have always felt that the Sequential Gearbox configuration is much much faster than a ordinary gearbox used in cars.

Why is this design used ? Any advantages?

Note: I am aware that racing cars(touring cars & rally cars) use Sequential transmissions, but why not everyday cars?

Comment: How does a sequential gearbox work when you come to a stop sign?  Is it like a motorcycle where you have to shift all the way back down?  If so, I really wouldn't want that in my car...

Comment: @JPhi1618 In many motorcycles with SEQ gearbox there is a leaver which will pull the tranny to neutral with just one tug no need to downshift through all gears.

Comment: Does an ordinary diver want to go though gears in sequence?  Do you?

Comment: Your are referring to manual correct?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Some cars have**

There was 50's era MG that used them.

I couple of model years of Toyota MR2.

The [E46 BMW M3](http://oppositelock.kinja.com/why-the-smg-m3-is-the-best-m3-1596497374).

Some reasons manufacturers that have used them and dropped them is user complaints.

- It shifts hard.
- The consumer isn't used to the idea of going down through all the gears just to get to 1st.
- It's louder and sounds unnerving
- In BMW's case consumers where allegedly bringing in their cars for warranty when nothing was wrong.

There are claims that they don't last as long as other transmission types although I am unable to validate that.

**In car racing, they are very popular**

Here's a website that builds them for various classes.  [GT1 and GT2 WEC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIA_World_Endurance_Championship) are rife with constant mesh sequential transmissions.

[Hollinger Racing](http://holinger.com.au/showroom/category/gear-sets-and-kits) builds them to swap out the stock transmissions of various homologated vehicles.

**But to me, an SMG is music**

Comment: The main reason most car guys don't use them is money. 10-15k for a sequential box is about 10x what most old fashioned manual transmissions cost brand new. If you throw in the prices on used transmissions, it's an even bigger difference.